# Non Right Triangle Proof

Tags: trigonometry

This is a question from Khan Academy that stumped me on the second part of it. I believe that my answers for the first and second parts are correct. I am just not seeing how to get the second.

[image]

Comment: You can use the little blue right triangle and the fact that $sin\theta=sin(180-\theta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, $\angle ACB= \pi-\angle BCD$
$\sin\angle BCD = \frac{h}{a}$
So, $\sin (\pi - \angle BCD)=sin \angle BCD=\sin \angle ACB = \frac{h}{a}$

 So, $h=a\sin C $

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You want to get angle BCD in terms of angle ACB, I think.